# set checkbox from checkboxlist to uncheck using jquery

Tags: jquery, checkboxlist

how to set one checkbox from asp.net checkboxlist control to unchecked where the index of the selected check box is i using jquery.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand you, you should be able to do something like:

```
$('input:checkbox').eq(i).removeAttr('checked');
```

To set it, you would use:

```
$('input:checkbox').eq(i).attr('checked','checked');
```

Note that the initial selector will get all the checkboxes on the page.  If you need to restrict it to just a subset of checkboxes on the page, adjust the initial selector -- based on a container or the naming scheme for the checkboxes - to deal with just the checkboxes in question.  I'm also assuming that you're using zero-based indexing for the checkbox in question.