# Jquery setting up a default value for checkbox on load or page

Tags: jquery

On load of the page I want to set it to FALSE immediately. How I can do that please? thanks

Comment: If you unconditionally want to do this all the time. Change the source of the page in the server, it's better.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
    $('#id_of_your_checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can execute methods when DOM is ready with [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) and you can change value of a checkbox with [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) like this;

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#id_of_checkbox').prop('checked', false);
})
```

For this example you have to give an id (`id_of_checkbox`) to your checbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myCheckbox").prop("checked", false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#checkboxId').removeAttr('checked');`

Answer (score 0):

Check [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) and [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function and take an idea from these code snippets to implement your functionality.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".myCheckbox").prop("checked", false);  // select by css class

    or  

   $("#myCheckbox").prop("checked", false);   // select by checkbox id
    });
```

or

```
$('.myCheckbox').removeAttr('checked')
```

**If you want to uncheck all checkbox on your page then try this:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("input[type='checkbox']").removeAttr('checked')   
})
```

check these links for more details

[Setting "checked" for a checkbox with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript)

[set checkbox from checkboxlist to uncheck using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883776/set-checkbox-from-checkboxlist-to-uncheck-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zfgFc/)
it will make check box selected randomly

To make it false, u can do

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[name='checkbxName']").removeAttr("checked");
})
```